# unscalable oldstyle numbers through \newfont with XeLaTeX (Minion)

Tags: xetex, fontspec, scaling, oldstylenums

In what is below, the `\newfont` command does not scale the numbers. I would like to know why.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Minion Pro}
\newfont{\myFont}{MinionPro-BoldCn.otf scaled 5000}
\begin{document}
\myFont 123456789 \Huge 123456789
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\newfont` is the (very) old LaTeX interface for defining a font, but it has always been a low level command. Higher level commands should be preferred when available.

The main problem with `\newfont` is that it defines a font at a *fixed* size.

However, `fontspec` provides `\newfontface` that looks like what you need:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Common, Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\newfontface{\myFont}[Scale=5]{Minion Pro Bold Cond}
\begin{document}
1234567890 \myFont 123456789 \Huge 123456789
\end{document}
```

(use the method that works for you in specifying the font name); I added also normal font digits for comparison.

[image]

All `fontspec` options can be added to `\newfontface`, for example old style numbers:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Common, Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\newfontface{\myFont}[Scale=5,Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro Bold Cond}
\begin{document}
1234567890 \myFont 123456789 \Huge 123456789
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but no, I would like the scale numbers to be oldstyle: you see?

Comment: @pluton I've added the option: it's just a matter of adding `Numbers=OldStyle` to the options.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the global option `Numbers=OldStyle` is not automatically accounted for?

Comment: @pluton The options given to `\setmainfont` are *not* global: they hold for the main font. Use `\defaultfontfeatures` for options you want to be set for all fonts defined from that point on.